# Como guardar y leer campos heredados en un archivo .DAT con java

Tags: java

Tengo una clase que hereda de otra y al momento de guardar los datos en un archivo, me guarda solo los campos de la clase hija pero no los de la clase padre. Este es el código de guardar y leer del archivo:

```
 public  void escribirArchivo(ArrayList<Atleta> atletas) throws IOException {
        try (ObjectOutputStream salida = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(this.nombreArchivo))) {
            
            salida.writeObject(atletas);
        }
    }
    
    
    public  ArrayList<Atleta> leerArchivo() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try (ObjectInputStream entrada = new ObjectInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(this.nombreArchivo))) {
            
            return (ArrayList<Atleta>) entrada.readObject();
        }
    }
```

Y esta es la clase atleta :

```
public class Atleta extends Persona implements Serializable  {

    /**
     * @return the nIDAtleta
     */
    public int getnIDAtleta() {
        return nIDAtleta;
    }

    /**
     * @param nIDAtleta the nIDAtleta to set
     */
    public void setnIDAtleta(int nIDAtleta) {
        this.nIDAtleta = nIDAtleta;
    }

    /**
     * @return the nivel
     */
    public int getNivel() {
        return nivel;
    }

    /**
     * @param nivel the nivel to set
     */
    public void setNivel(int nivel) {
        this.nivel = nivel;
    }
    private int nIDAtleta;
    private int nivel;

   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione, tenía que ponerle el implements Serializable en la clase padre y con eso se arreglaba:

```
public class Persona implements Serializable{
```